# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, zend-framework

When I run this command `php -v`
this error comes up:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/dom.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/dom.so: undefined symbol: php_libxml_node_free_list in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/xmlreader.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/xmlreader.so: undefined symbol: dom_node_class_entry in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/xsl.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/xsl.so: undefined symbol: dom_node_class_entry in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP 7.1.5-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 (cli) (built: May 22 2017 13:39:01) ( NTS )
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.1.7-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Anybody can help me?

Comment: I think the error message explains itself, it cant find the dynamic libraries it is expecting at the locations it is telling you about. First thing to do would be to check they exist

Comment: But I don't know  how to locate the xmlreader.so, @PeterFeatherstone

Comment: The path is given to you...

Answer (score 64):

Safe solution is to reinstall all php7 related packages.

You can do it by simply entering this command to console:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall `dpkg -l | grep 'ii  php7' | awk '{ printf($2" "); next}'`
```

This solution will keep your configuration unchanged

Comment: Thankfully, it worked for my ubuntu 14.04, but I have the same problem with my mac......

Comment: Thank you. It worked on ubuntu 14.04 in the 2015 directory.

Comment: Working! but in case I will need to replace php7 to php7.1

Comment: Don't forget to change the "grep" part if you want to focus on the 7.1 version only (you may have both 7.0 and 7.1 installed packages...)

Comment: this worked for me. somehow things broke after an upgrade to php7.2 but this fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

(In ubuntu 14.04 or above)

> sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0 libphp7.0-embed libssl-dev
>   openssl php7.0-cgi php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-dev php7.0-fpm
>   php7.0-phpdbg

reference:

https://gnh1201.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/php-7-0-undefined-symbol-php_libxml_node_free_list/

Answer (score 6):

I found almost the same problem with xml after linux update (and PHP 7.0 -> 7.1 with it).

The solution for me was pretty simple:

```
sudo apt install php7.1-xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same errors. The reportedly missing files were present, the file permissions looked ok to me, and PHP was executed using the correct user and group.

For me it helped, to remove all PHP packages and do a fresh start.

1. The following command should **remove all PHP packages** on a Debian/Ubuntu systems (**including the PHP config** - make a backup before):

   ```
   sudo aptitude purge `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
   ```

   Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/187278
2. Check if PHP was removed:

   ```
   php -v
   ```

   This should return something like "command not found: php".
3. Then, install PHP again, e.g.:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-xml php7.1-fpm php7.1-json
   ```

Comment: Your solution will remove package configuration. Check my answer for fix without deleting configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Depending on the configuration, starting with a fresh one, might be a good idea (or not). I added a warning though! :)

Answer (score -1):

In my case some php packages were not upgraded, so I simply had to perform a dist-upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```