# Ubuntu 18.04 - why these errors?

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to Ubuntu, I have `18.04` installed, also installed xampp...
I created a laravel project in `/var/www/html/` called imanager
but when i try to run `php artisan command` I get the following errors...

I have tried to look for answers in the net but nothing working...

any and all help would be appreciated... thanks you in advance

> leoza@LZ-4:/var/www/html/imanager$ php artisan
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xml.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/xml.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/xml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/xml.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/xml.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'dom.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/dom.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/dom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/dom.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/dom.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/gd.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/gd.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/gd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'simplexml.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/simplexml.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/simplexml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/simplexml.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/simplexml.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'wddx.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/wddx.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/wddx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/wddx.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/wddx.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xmlreader.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/xmlreader.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/xmlreader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/xmlreader.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/xmlreader.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xmlrpc.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/xmlrpc.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/xmlrpc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/xmlrpc.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/xmlrpc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xmlwriter.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/xmlwriter.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/xmlwriter.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/xmlwriter.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/xmlwriter.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/xsl.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/xsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/xsl.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/xsl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/imanager/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/imanager/artisan on line 18
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/imanager/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/imanager/artisan on line 18

Comment: Can you check with `php.ini` that those modules are enabled?

Comment: php.ini is not the problem, it's that PHP tries to load modules that are not installed. Just install the according PHP packages. If that doesn't work, you might have messed up your installation. In that case, purging the whole, deleteng the remainders manually and reinstalling would be my approach.

Comment: Try https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/

Comment: Error itself say that it is unable to load libraries. You can link to install all package https://websiteforstudents.com/install-phpmyadmin-apache2-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-beta-server/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132635/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your responses..... i took the advice of Ulrich Eckhardt and did a flush and reinstall, used the links from A. Meshu and  Sundar Ban and I am glad to report that all is up and working great...thank you all for taking the time to answer, I rally appreciate it :-)

Comment: I am fairly new to this site, is there anyway for me to pick your comments as correct response? @UlrichEckhardt A. Meshu, Sandar Ban