# php: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl'

Tags: php, xslt, module

on my ubuntu 20.04, I could never resolve this issue, which is crucial for a very much desired application:

```
$ php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/xsl (/usr/lib/php/20190902/xsl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/xsl.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/xsl.so: undefined symbol: dom_node_class_entry)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Of course, I looked up `/usr/lib/php/20190902`, but xsl seems to be there:

```
$ ls -al /usr/lib/php/20190902/xsl*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 35080 Jun 13 15:43 /usr/lib/php/20190902/xsl.so
```

What else could be wrong?

Cheers,
Wolf

Comment: How does your appropriate xsl.ini file look like? Mine has this line: `extension=xsl.so`

Comment: `locate xsl.ini` finds these four files: 

/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini   ---   /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xsl.ini   ---   /usr/share/php7.4-xml/xml/xsl.ini   ---   /var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:php:7.4:mods-available:xsl.ini

All of them do have the contents `extension=xsl.so`.

Is it good to have all these config files?

Comment: Seems to be ok.

Comment: You have this in error message: `undefined symbol: dom_node_class_entry`. May be [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132635/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library) can help you?